# PHP displaying data from MySQL with JOINS

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

Im using PHP 5.6 and I have php errors on and everything And I got none.

My PHP CODE

```
$GetAllServers  = $db->select("SELECT * FROM panel_servers ORDER BY id ASC");
$GetAllGroups   = $db->select("SELECT * FROM panel_admin_groups ORDER BY id");
$GetAllAdmins   = $db->select("SELECT *, s.name server_name, g.name group_name, a.pid pid
    FROM panel_admins a 
    LEFT JOIN panel_players p ON a.pid = p.id 
    LEFT JOIN panel_admin_groups g ON a.gid = g.id 
    LEFT JOIN panel_countries c ON p.country = c.country_code 
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT `username`, `pid` FROM panel_players_username GROUP BY pid ORDER BY last_used DESC) u ON a.pid = u.pid 
        LEFT JOIN panel_servers s ON a.sid = s.id WHERE (TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, add_time, now()) < g.usetime OR g.usetime = 0) ORDER BY immunity DESC");
```

My HTML CODE

```
<?php
$Players = array();
foreach ((array)$GetAllAdmins as $admin)
    if(!in_array($admin['steamid'], $Players))
        array_push($Players, $admin['steamid']);
        $avatars = GetPlayersAvatars($Players);
?>
<?php foreach ((array) $GetAllAdmins as $admin) { 
    if(!empty($admin['steamid'])){?>
        <tr>
            <td class="coutryrow"><img src="<?=WEBSITE;?>/img/flag/<?=$admin['country_name'];?>.png" title="<?=$admin['country_name'];?>" class="flag"></td>
            <td>
                <a target="_blank" href="http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/<?=$admin['steamid'];?>">
                    <img src="<?=$avatars[$admin['steamid']]?>" class="player-avatar">
                    <?=(!empty($admin['player_username'])) ? htmlspecialchars($admin['player_username']) : htmlspecialchars($avatars['username-'.$admin['steamid']]);?>
                </a>
             </td>
             <td class="centerrow"><?=htmlspecialchars($admin['group_name']);?></td>
             <td class="centerrow"><?=htmlspecialchars($admin['server_name']);?></td>
             <td class="centerrow"><?=date(TIMEFORMAT, strtotime($admin['add_time']));?></td>
             <td class="centerrow"><a href="<?=$CurrentURL;?>edit/<?=intval($admin['aid']);?>/" class="btn btn-info btn-mini"><span class="icon"> <i class="icooo-on-edit"></i> </span><?= _("Edit");?></a></td>
         </tr>

         <?php } else {echo "<tr><td>-</td></tr>";} } ?>
```

I want to display in the HTML a list of all admins that are added to the database, but for example the name is in a table and the flags are in another table. With the JOINS and everything I want to  display on the html as you can see.

Comment: You use join with panel_admin_groups and panel_players so maybe those have nothing in common. Tell us what you want to get and maybe provide more code or try to use this query with 1 join then with 2 ,then 3 and then tell where you get a problem

Comment: @O.Rares I want to display in the HTML a list of all admins that are added to the database, but for example the name is in a table the flags are in other table and with the JOINS and everything i want like to join them something like that and then display on the html as you can see, I have a lot more code here but I cant display here because it is a lot, and I dont know if is going to help with anything, is there a way to send private messages here or something?

Comment: I posted a possible answer based on your description. Private messages can be send if you have a private chat that is for teams

Answer (score 0):

If you want the last admins added in the database use this query

```
$GetAllAdmins   = $db->select("SELECT steamid, s.name server_name, g.name group_name, a.pid pid FROM panel_admins a 
                                        LEFT JOIN panel_admin_groups g ON a.gid = g.id 
                                        LEFT JOIN panel_servers s ON a.sid = s.id WHERE (TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, add_time, now()) < g.usetime OR g.usetime = 0) ORDER BY immunity DESC");
```

You need 3 columns. If you want to add a filter add it in the WHERE clause

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: steamid

Comment: @EddieMarks I added steamid to select but didn't put the table to search in it,like admin.steamid

Comment: it didnt worked, I m using a project from github, if you could just check it to see the full code I would be gratefull (https://github.com/boomix/BoomPanel)

Comment: @EddieMarks what errors did you got? Looks like you didn't changed the code from the github, maybe your tables aren't the same

Comment: Do you have records in your db ?

Comment: @EddieMarks on the Github it says that this part of code is not yet finished so you can't use it unless you write your own code. The code is correct, but you have to do more functionality in other files.

Comment: Just wanted to print the admins in the table bp_admins to a html table and yes i have records in my db, i tried to install with the same name on the tables and I get no print to the html

Comment: @EddieMarks Create your own controller and view and use my code. If you want to edit the existing code from the github and make it working you have to check for the missing parts